# Passing facebook access token to server backend

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have an Android app that I built that logins with facebook android sdk.
It recieves a long term access token (the one you normaly get with a default login button). And pass it to a server backend.

The server backend login to facebook with the access token.

The app is in release mode (signed apk).

The problem is, This works only for me (the developer). When distributing the app to my friends, the app logins to facebook but the server backend can't use the token (for them, for my account this works fine).

The facebook app is not in sandbox mode (in sandbox mode, only I can login with the android app. You see everyone can login with the android app now, problem is, only i the developer can forward the token to the server and use it).

Anyone knows why?

Comment: does it says any error when trying to login using another account except developer one ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Heshan for the quick reply.

For whoever encounters a similar problem in the future the problem was:

Server backend runs an HTTP server, if someone logins with the website, the server asks for permissions: public_profile (default), email.

Android application didn't have permissions set so it only asked for public_profile (default), and not email.

Since I logged with the website first, my account had two permissions for the app.

All the others logged with the Android app, and only approved public_profile. Hence the error.

Comment: What does the email permission have to do with the access token?

Comment: I didn't want their email, but for some reason without the email permission I could not login.